# Is it possible to retain captured image in app storage even after deleted from Gallery in android?

Tags: android, camera, storage

I want to show Captured image in gallery as well as in my app.Now if image deleted from gallery image will deleted from app storage? I want to retain image and show in my app even after deleted from Gallery.How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 folder to store image.

Create `.nomedia` file in one of the folder so that every media file that is inside of the folder will not be seen in the gallery.

Create 2 copy of the images one in `.nomedia` file folder and one in normal folder and use that folder to show files in your application.

Comment: If it solve your case and mark it answered so other can get to know.